# Help needed for Hardware Upgrade in order to bring the batch time down by 50%

Tags: laptop, desktop

I have SQL Server Express on my Laptop with following configuration

Model: HP 240 (F6Q29PA)
Processor:Intel Core I3-3110M CPU@2.4 Ghz
RAM : 2GB
HDD : 500 GB (should be sufficient)
Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit OS

I run my batch job doing stock analysis every weekend and it takes about 15 hours to finish. I've burned up three home laptops in six years. So I am looking to have a more professional machine for it. The desired specifications are:

1. The machine should have cooling sufficient for sustained use over many hours.
2. Better CPU and RAM to bring the time down to 7-8 hours (10 hours is passable too). This would allow daily runs instead of weekly.

When the job is running, the machine may be used for light duty such as Excel. No graphics performance requirement. A desktop is acceptable, as I have no space restrictions. However, desktops seem harder to find now than laptops.

My budget is Rs 30-40k ($450-600).

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry. I didn't realize this question hasn't got an official answer even though I bought a machine based on the comments. For what its worth, I bought an HP Eltebook 8470P with 256 GB SSD, 8 GB RAM. My Batch time got dropped from 14 hours or so to 5 hours. Has worked like a peach for 2 years till a couple of days back when its power adapter went kaput. Came here to ask about it only when notice this question lying unanswered. Thank everyone, though belated....